# Installation Yii2 Advanced template not working

Tags: yii, yii2, bower, yii2-advanced-app, bower-install

When I try to deploy the Yii2 advanced template, I always end up with a not working application.

The error message is:

> Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException
>   The file or directory to be published does not exist:
>   [...]/yii-application/**vendor/bower/jquery/dist**

I tried to install via the recent composer version, with and without the  the fxp asset plugin. The error message is same for both.

I used the official documentaion for the installation on my Ubuntu64 16.04 webserver.

Comment: Check your vendor folder if there is `bower` folder or `bower-asset` folder.

Comment: There is just `bower-asset`, no `bower`
Subfolders: bootstrap, inputmask, jquery, punycode, typeahead.js, yii2-pjax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your composer configuration creates `bower-asset` folder instead of `bower` you can modify `composer.json` and reupdate project (1) or modify paths configuration (2).

(1) I'm not sure what is the best solution here (maybe someone else can share) - with current version of composer and fx plugin there is some problem with paths configuration. Old `asset-installer-paths` in `extra` section should work but it triggers warning for deprecated configuration.

(2) Add in the common configuration file:

```
'aliases' => [
    '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
    '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
],
```

This will change paths to assets and all should work fine.