# Yii2 Testing error while codeception run command is issued

Tags: php, testing, yii2, composer-php, codeception

I've got a test suite in yii2 that I would like to run, I have installed composer, codeception, built the test with 'codecept build' and so far so good, everything was smooth as butter until I've issued the command 'codecept run'; it throws an error which by any means I have tried to figured out unfortunately unsuccessfully. I have reinstalled composer, clear the composer cache, rebuilt the project again with codecept build but not success whatsoever.

The error is as follows:

```
 MyApp\tests.functional Tests (4) -----------------------------------------------------------------
- HomeCest: Check open<pre>PHP User Error &#039;yii\base\ErrorException&#039; with message &#039;Exception &#039;yii\base\InvalidParamException&#039; with message &#039;The file or directory to be published does not exist: /home/user/GIT_MyApp/yii/myapp/vendor/bower/jquery/dist&#039; 

in /home/user/GIT_MyApp/yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetManager.php:453

Stack trace:
#0 /home/user/GIT_MyApp/yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetBundle.php(185): yii\web\AssetManager-&gt;publish(&#039;/home/angelo/GI...&#039;, Array)
#1 /home/user/GIT_MyApp/yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetManager.php(268): yii\web\AssetBundle-&gt;publish(Object(yii\web\AssetManager))
#2 

/home/user/GIT_MyApp/yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetManager.php(239): yii\web\AssetManager-&gt;loadBundle(&#039;yii\\web\\JqueryA...&#039;, Array, true) 
.....
.....
```

The weirdest thing though, is that the same project runs fine in another machine (CENT OS). Mine is Kubuntu 16.04. Could it be the machine? 
Could someone please tell me what is happening and why this error keeps on coming?

Comment: Can anyone point me somewhere?

Comment: Are composer dependencies updated? If so is the problem source similar to one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44669167/3364821)?

Comment: Yes, composer dependencies are all updated.

Comment: the problem seems to be that the path to assets directory is constructed wrongly - it sticks the app name into the path i.e. <yii's root>/<app-name>/vendor instead of looking under <yii's root>/vendor but I don't know why

Comment: Any suggestion guys?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `fxp/composer-asset-plugin` with composer globally:
`composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.3.1"`

Like here: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/2.0.12/.travis.yml#L20

Comment: I don't know the root cause, but the error you got is caused by that plugin. Sometimes the solution is to bump the required version. I am just following composer.json changes in yii2-app-basic.

Comment: Are you using yii2-app-basic? What version? The last build of master branch actually failed, because they tried to move this dependency to composer.json https://travis-ci.org/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/builds/243991504

Comment: Using the yii2-app-advanced, version 2.0.12. I don't think is related to yii packages though since as I've said earlier in another machine codeception run successfully the tests. Is on one machine that I am having the issue and I think is related to some configurations, but no clue whatsoever.